# copy a string of characters in an other string using dynamic memory alocation but it doesn t works

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to copy a string of characters in another string using dynamic memory allocation but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* s1, * s2, * s3;
    s1 = (char*)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    s2 = (char*)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    s3 = (char*)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(s1, 11, stdin);
    fgets(s2, 11, stdin);
    int i = 0;
    do {
        *(s3 + i) = *(s1 + i);
        i++;
    } while (*(s1 + i) != '\n' && *(s1 + i) != '\0');
    puts(s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Thanks to @yano we know, that it should compile. What do you expect as output? 

Maybe you don't get what you expect, because you are not using s2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc. C automatically promotes it from a void pointer to the correct type. Refrain from using pointer notations, (*(s1+ i) , is hard to read and understand.  State what exactly doesn't work? What output were you expecting? Did it issue any warnings?

Comment: Avram Bogdan, post input used, output seen, output exepcted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not null terminate the `s3` string.

```
    } while (*(s1 + i) != '\n' && *(s1 + i) != '\0');
    s3[i] = 0;
    puts(s3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug here: `} while (*(s1 + i) != '\n' && *(s1 + i) != '\0');`.

This means that you stop copying at `\n` which `fgets` will place in the buffer but you do not null terminate the string `s3`.

So if `s1` looks like `"hello\n\0"` then `s3` will end up as `"hello\n"` without null terminator.

Corrected and de-obfuscated loop:

```
size_t i;
for(i=0; s1[i]!='\n' && s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
  s3[i] = s1[i];
}
s3[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: potential UB if input is longer than the limit and fgets will not put '\n'.

Comment: @0___________ Well that's a different problem and we can't answer/assume that unless we know the input. But sure this could be made fool-proof as `s[i]!='\n' && s[i]!='\0'`. Still the input should be santisized where it is taken and not in some unrelated copy code.

Comment: @Lundin we have to assume any lentht input. Your solution will work only in limited number of cases

Comment: @0___________ I updated the loop to make everyone but the optimizing compiler happy.

Comment: where is that optimization?

Comment: @0___________ The loop condition includes multiple branches so it's not great. But we're talking micro-optimizations I guess.

Comment: I see same number of branches https://godbolt.org/z/xx6Ejdsb4

Comment: @0___________ I meant between the version only checking for \n and the version checking for \n + \0.

Comment: we can generalize it: two codes doing something different may (and probably will) have different number of branches :)